# Creating an central multi-purpose dictionary / database

Tags: software, workflow

I am trying to organize my workflow and make it more effective.

As non-native English-speaker studying in a foreign country I often need to look-up domain-specific translations (in 3 languages). As there are no specific dictionaries I am using textfiles containing translations I have collected over the time. 
This is quite uncomfortable.

Often these words are related to some kind of mathematical definition which has to be stated as a theorem for proofs. Right now I usually copy these from my old publications.

It would be great to have some kind of central dictionary or knowledge-base where I could organize all this (Translations and Definitions).

- Anyone who can recommend a program for this?
- How do you organize definitions and domain-specific translations?

Comment: The question was intended to be more about managing knowledge than actual coding, the technical things were used to illustrate the intention, I changed the Question. Hope its more on-topic now.

Comment: thanks for editing into something more appropriate for the site (and welcome to Academia Stack Exchange!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try http://termbases.eu/ a site that was mentioned under [Software: Lexicons](http://linguistlist.org/sp/GetWRListings.cfm?WRAbbrev=Software#wr102) in Linguist List.

Broadly, what you have described is a lightweight variety of a [dictionary writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_writing_system), software for developing a lexicon.

If you were translating digital documents, I would recommend [translation memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory) software. Collecting and managing your multilingual context-specific translations is part of what translation memory software does.

Another possibility, if you happen to be comfortable setting up a wiki, is to create a wiki in the manner of [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/).

Comment: The first website you introduced seems not to be free and has limitations over the free version. Do you know some open-source/free softwares or website services too?